# rstan() should not run in #'@example?

Tags: rstan

In package development, each example requires <5s. However, the pair of `stan_model()` and  `rstan::sampling()` take long  times more than 5s as follows:

```
    Examples with CPU or elapsed time > 5s
                     user system elapsed
   fit               1.25   0.11   32.47
```

So I put `\donttest{}` for each `rstan::sampling()` in roxygen comments `#'@examples`

In examples`#'@examples`, we should not run `sampling()` or  is there any treatment ?

---

I had tried to create my package based on the code `rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA')` when I was taught from you (Thank you !!)  but, I do not understand many things about it.

Previously, `rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA')`  launched the errors in my computer ( but now the error does not occur).
So, I made my package without the `rstan_package_skeleton()`, say `BayesianAAA`, and in my original making, I put the `Model_A.stan`,`Model_B.stan`,`Model_C.stan`,.... in the `inst/extdata` and I refer my stan files as follows;

```
  scr <- system.file("extdata", "Model_A.stan", package="BayesianAAA")

  scr <- rstan::stan_model(scr)
```

I have many questions about the code `rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA')`.

**1) The first question** is How to include my existing stan files and **how to refer** my `.stan` files for the `rstan::stan_model()` ?
  According to the page following page, it said that

*If we had existing .stan files to include with the package we could use the optional `stan_files` argument to rstan_package_skeleton to include them.*

So, I think I should execute, I am not sure but the following like manner is required;

```
`rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA', stan_files = "Model_A.stan" )`.
```

But I do not know how to write the code for several stan files, say `Model_A.stan`,`Model_B.stan`,`Model_C.stan` in my existing package made without the `rstan_package_skeleton()`. I do not understand , but the following code is correct ? Since I do not where the files described in the variable `stan_files` is reflected in the new project created by the `rstan_package_skeleton()`.

```
`rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA', stan_files = c("Model_A.stan",`Model_B.stan`,`Model_C.stan` )`.
```

Here, the another question arise, that is,

**2) The second question:**   Where I execute the code `rstan_package_skeleton(path = 'BayesianAAA', stan_files = "Model_A.stan" )` ? I execute it form the R studio console in my existing package project. Is it correct ? And then, the new project arise and it is contained the old existing project. What should I do ?

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/rstantools/vignettes/minimal-rstan-package.html

**3)** I do not quite know about the packages  "**rstanarm**" , but I try to imitate it for my package, but I can not fined any `.stan` file in it, I am wrong ?

I am sorry for my poor English, and Lack of study about these things.
I would be grateful if you could tell me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You generally should not be writing a package that calls `stan_model` at runtime, unless like **brms** or **tmbstan** you are generating a Stan program at runtime as opposed to writing it statically. There are dozens of packages on CRAN that provide compiled Stan programs basically by following the build process developed for **rstanarm**, which is facilitated by the `rstantools::rstan_package.skeleton` function, the [step-by-step guide](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstantools/vignettes/minimal-rstan-package.html), and the [developer guidelines](https://cran.r-project.org/package=rstantools/vignettes/developer-guidelines.html) which directly address your question

> CRAN policy permits long installation times but imposes restrictions on the time consumed by examples and unit tests that are much shorter than the time that it takes to compile even a simple Stan program. Thus, it is only possible to adequately test your package if it has pre-compiled Stan programs.

Even then, it can be difficult to sample from a posterior distribution (adequately) in five seconds, so you often have to use small datasets, one chain, a small number of iterations, etc.

It is best to pass the names of your Stan programs (which should end in a .stan extension, not use a period otherwise, and only have ASCII letters, numbers, and the underscore in their names) to `rstantools::rstan_package_skeleton()`. If doing so from RStudio, I would call it while not in an existing project. Then

> During installation, all Stan programs will be compiled and saved in the list `stanmodels` that can then be used by R function in the package. The rule is that the Stan program compiled from the model code in `src/stan_files/foo.stan` is stored as list element `stanmodels$foo`.

There are dozens of R packages that have Stan programs in their `src/stan_files` directory (although the locations of the Stan programs are going to move to `inst/stan` for the next **rstantools** release) that for the most part just followed the vignettes and did not have to do any additional steps except write more R functions.

Comment: Thank you for reply.  I have many questions and write it in the above. I'd appreciate it if you could answer my questions.

Comment: Thank you for your second reply !! Your reply always increase my motivation.
(I did not notice your second answer.)

I understand that a file named `xxx.stan`   is compiled and it can be refered as an R object of list named `stanmodel`.